# Java annotation force write the javadoc

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

It's possible to create a custom annotation to force that a method have a javadoc?

I would like to create an annotation that check if method follow specific rules. And I cannot understand how to check the javadoc.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are tools to hunt for missing javadoc, but nothing can be forced (unless you use some stick on your devs :p)

Comment: is that for you to monitor your sourcecode? what IDE are you using?

Comment: I would like that the javac fail the compilation in a method, with that annotation, if the method doesn't follow rules.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod) to check the methods contain the javadoc.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple of Custom Annotation with checkstyle lib please?

Comment: You do not to create a custom annotation. Checkstyle is a tool used to check the quality of your source code. One of the checks it can perform is checking if your methods contain javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Eclipse** as IDE then you can set a compiler-flag that is showing errors if no javadoc is detected (use that carefully since that is quite verbose!)..

[image]